# How to apply styling to a HTML text that doesn't have a tag

Tags: html, css

Basically, I'm looking for the cleanest way to modify the styling of some text that i have in the application views without having to reprogram them.

I have a lot of section that does not have any tag (text without tag in the view).

Is there a way to apply styling to that specific text? (Solution for the short term, before I redefine correctly the tags in the while views)

Comment: You will have to wrap the text in tag some way or an other. Either in the markup either with JS but that can become a hassle if you have a lot of text to style.

Comment: please show some of the mark up you are looking to edit. It's possible to add *some* styling via javascript or jquery, although this should be kept to an absolute minimum, if used at all

Answer (score 0):

Except for a [small number of narrowly defined places](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements), you can't apply CSS to anything other than an element.

So: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify the first line you could use:

```
p:first-line {
   font-weight: 700;
   color: green;
}
```

otherwise you'll have to wrap the text in a tag. Other psuedo elements you could use are here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp

Comment: Because `:first-word` doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add style to a something that doesn't have an element. A simple div tag can change that, and its a really easy and quick fix. Just div a section, give it an id or class, then modify it using css.